# make error with smart card reader driver install

Tags: drivers, smartcard

I purchased a smart card reader, zoweetek 12026-1, for which i will need to install pcsc and ccid drivers. 
I have successfully install pcsc-lite-1.8.6 but when i tried to install ccid-1.4.5-alcor i got the following error during `./configure`.

Both drivers were downloaded from the zoweetek website

```
 ./configure 

 bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

which i "solved" by `chmod +x configure`

But when I ran `make` I got the following error

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/matt/9540-V2/ccid-1.4.5.1 alcor/examples'  
  CC     scardcontrol-scardcontrol.o  
scardcontrol.c: In function ‘main’:  
scardcontrol.c:754:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]    
     (void)fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin);  
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scardcontrol.c: At top level:  
scardcontrol.c:816:1: fatal error: opening dependency file 
.deps/scardcontrol-scardcontrol.Tpo: Permission denied  } /* main */
 ^
compilation terminated.  
Makefile:322: recipe for target 'scardcontrol-scardcontrol.o' failed  
make[2]: *** [scardcontrol-scardcontrol.o] Error 1  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/matt/9540-V2/ccid-1.4.5.1-alcor/examples'
Makefile:345: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed  
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/matt/9540-V2/ccid-1.4.5.1-alcor'  
Makefile:274: recipe for target 'all' failed  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And as a consequence of this, `make install` didn't work either.

I tried to find a newer one (mainly on GitHub) but didn't and since I'm not even sure about what the error message means, I thought it would be better to ask before I start to messing up my Ubuntu installation.

requested lsusb -t output

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 29, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device,       Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 29, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 32, If 0, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

installed the suggested package, but i recieved the following error msg in the terminal:

```
Gdk-Message: Window 0x56282676daf0 is a temporary window without parent, application will not be able to position it on screen.
Gdk-Message: Window 0x56282676daf0 is a temporary window without parent, application will not be able to position it on screen.

(cardpeek:16708): Gdk-CRITICAL **: xdg_popup_configure: assertion 'impl->transient_for' failed
Gdk-Message: Window 0x5628267afc80 is a temporary window without parent, application will not be able to position it on screen.
Gdk-Message: Window 0x5628267afc80 is a temporary window without parent, application will not be able to position it on screen.

(cardpeek:16708): Gdk-CRITICAL **: xdg_popup_configure: assertion 'impl->transient_for' failed
Gdk-Message: Window 0x56282676daf0 is a temporary window without parent, application will not be able to position it on screen.
Gdk-Message: Window 0x56282676daf0 is a temporary window without parent, application will not be able to position it on screen.

(cardpeek:16708): Gdk-CRITICAL **: xdg_popup_configure: assertion 'impl->transient_for' failed
```

seems like two times the same messages.. which i indeed get after running cardpeek only once!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post with the output of `lsusb -t`? This will tell us what kind of smart card reader you have. Chances is it's supported by some package in Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, so it's not claimed. Can you try `sudo apt install cardpeek pcscd libpcsclite1 libccid` and then run cardpeek to see if your reader is detected?

Comment: did so, and it seems like it is working. but not sure.

Comment: A good tip is to always try the packages from repositories before building from source. Repositories are kept updated by the Ubuntu team.

Comment: i understand, just wasn't aware of a package being available.  should've looked though. anyways i do get a terminal error message. 

the app replies with the following: [i] Possibly identified card () :> Belgium Electronic ID card, which is correct. and it says that even when i pick another scripit from the analyzer drop down menu. I do not get to see any info on the card though, nor do i get a request for the pincode with which it is protected. 

the terminal gives the error i edited into the question.

Comment: Please make a new question on how to use smartcards in Ubuntu.

Comment: i will do just so.  but first i will do some investigation myself. no need to ask if i can self educate ;) thanks a lot for your help!